# how to send push notifications to multiple apps in a single api call

Tags: push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

how can I send a push notification to multiple apps in a single api call. I can't find it anywhere in the documentation but I am able to do the same thing via dashboard. Hence, I feel there might be something that is missing. Eg. I want to send the push message to both the apps i.e hmspushapp1 and hmspushapp2 inside in hms project. Can you please guide me on how can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can send message to both the apps(which is under same project) using your project id. Please follow the below steps:

1. Sign in to AppGallery Connect, select My projects, find your project in the project list and go to Project settings there you can get your project id:

[image]

2. Collect the push tokens from both the apps which you need to send push messages
3. Call the access token API with any on of your app id and app secret.

https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/token

4. Make the below API to send a message from any API tool like postman with project id and push tokens.

[https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v2/\[projectid\]/messages:send](https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v2/%5C%5Bprojectid%5C%5D/messages:send)

(Replace the [projectid] with the id you have copied from the AGC console and place access token in its header as Bearer token)

5. In the request body, you can paste the collected tokens in token array(comma separated).

Please refer the below image:
[image]